# Avoiding RequireJS circular dependencies

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, modules, require.js

My `app` module bootstraps a Backbone.js application.
**I need `app` to be available in every other view** for easy access to router, triggering navigation, etc.

I never ported an app to RequireJS before, and I got stuck on circular dependency problem, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17148715/458193) isn't quite clear to me, so I'm not sure if I applied the solution correctly.

I'm using [AMD sugar style](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html#sugar) throughout the app, so here's what I came up with:

#### app.js

```
define(function (require, exports) {

  'use strict';

  var _ = require('underscore'),
      Backbone = require('backbone'),
      Router = require('Router'),
      AppView = require('common/views/app_view'),

  // ...

  return _.extend(exports, {
    start: function () {
      this.router = new Router();
      Backbone.history.start();

      this.appView = new AppView();
      this.appView.render();
    },

    // ...
  });

});
```

Extending `exports` instead of directly returning an object allows me to do `app = require('app')` in any view of the app without worrying about circular dependencies.

All other modules in the app return value normally (i.e. I'm not using `exports` anywhere else).

Is this an OK strategy for a Require.js Backbone app?
Are there better solutions (that will also work with [optimizer](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html) or [Almond](https://github.com/jrburke/almond))?

An example of how I'm using `app` in a (rather deeply nested) view:

#### zine_item_view.js

```
define(function (require) {

  'use strict';

  var View = require('common/views/view'),
      Misc = require('common/helpers/misc'),
      app = require('app');

  var ZineItemView = View.extend({
    template: 'templates/social/items/zine_item.html',

    events: {
      'click': 'showZine'
    },

    showZine: function (e) {
      if (!Misc.shouldHandleClick(e)) {
        return;
      }

      app.presenter.showZine({
        zine: this.model,
        route: app.router.routeToZineTrending(this.model.id)
      });
    }
  });

  return ZineItemView;

});
```

Comment: From an MVC perspective, your views should not have access to router or be able to trigger navigation. Don't get me wrong, I employ a similar scheme, but I think this is wrong.

Comment: Can you also post one of your views that would use `app` ?

Comment: Sorry if I am dense, but what is `app.presenter.showZine` supposed to do here ? Are you setting a route inside of a `View` ?

Comment: @konijn: `presenter` is not a view, it's a separate object that has methods like `showZine`, `showUser`, `showHome`, etc. Think of it as of a simple “controller” (although there are no controllers in Backbone per se). It manages the root view. It often needs to load a model asynchronously, and, when it is ready, updates both root view and the current route.

Answer (score 5):

There are few ways to solve your problem with Backbone.js + Require.js and executing functions or changing routes from view.

### 1. Using Backbone.Router

Here is approach I've used multiple times:

```js
'use strict';

// Your view --------------
define([
    'jquery'
    'backbone'
    'common/views/view',
    'common/helpers/misc'
], function ($, Backbone, View, Misc) {

    var ZineItemView = View.extend({
        ...
        showZine: function (e) {
          if (!Misc.shouldHandleClick(e)) {
            return;
          }
          // Pass all control from view to the router,
          // see http://stackoverflow.com/a/20311253/1363799
          Backbone.history.navigate('yourUrl_to_zine');
        }
    });

    return ZineItemView;
});

// Main block --------------
require([
    'jquery'
    'backbone',
    'app',
    'ZineItemView'
], function($, Backbone, App, ZineItemView) {
    ...

    var app = new App();

    var zineItemView = new ZineItemView({...});

    // Router way       
    var router = Backbone.Router.extend({
      routes: {
        "yourUrl_to_zine": "showZine"
      },
      showZine: function() {
            // Here you gave access to zineItemView.model and zineItemView.model.id
            app.presenter.showZine({
                zine: zineItemView.model,
                // I think next row becames obsolete
                route: app.router.routeToZineTrending(zineItemView.model.id)
            });
        }
    });
});
```

### 2. Event-driven approach

```
'use strict';

// Your view --------------
define([
    'jquery',
    'backbone',
    'common/views/view',
    'common/helpers/misc'
], function ($, Backbone, View, Misc) {

    var ZineItemView = View.extend({
        ...
        showZine: function (e) {
          if (!Misc.shouldHandleClick(e)) {
            return;
          }

          var view = this;

          // Trigger global event with desired parameters
          $(window).trigger('showZine.App', {
            zine: view.model,
            modelId: view.model.id // probably it's obsolete, because you can get it from zine property
          });
        }
    });

    return ZineItemView;
});

// Somewhere in app block --------------
// lodash is a dependency, because we use bind method
var App = {
    initialize: function() {
        $(window).on('showZine.App', _.bind(this.presenter.showZine, this) );
    },
    presenter: {
        showZine: function(event, paramsObj) {
            // Here you have paramsObj,
            // with paramsObj.zine = zineItemView.model
            // and paramsObj.modelId = zineItemView.model.id

            // Call app.router.routeToZineTrending from here, but be aware about value of `this` and `app` variables
        }
    }
};
```

### 3. Syntax of module defining (optional)

It preferentual, but seems to be a standart (it's easier to see dependencies):

```
'use strict';

define([
    'common/views/view',
    'common/helpers/misc',
    'app'
], function (View, Misc, app) {

    var ZineItemView = View.extend({
        ...
    });

    return ZineItemView;
});
```

Comment: You are welcome :). I'm also looking for more robust solution which somebody could propose.